# Filter products in the catalog grid in Magento admin panel that do not have any image attached

Tags: magento2

Can I display all **products** in the catalog grid in the Magento admin panel that don't have **Image** attached?
In the past, products have been created without images, and that's what we're looking for!

Comment: I think you have to use the import/export tool instead.